# why this syntax can pattern this "for" macro?

Tags: macros, scheme

```
#lang racket
(define-syntax for
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ list 'as element body ...)
     (map (lambda (element)
            body ...)
          list))))
```

> >
>       (for '(0 1 2 3 4) 'in i
>         (print i)
>         (newline))

=>
0
1
2
3
4
'(# # # # #)

My question is why the symbol 'in can pattern the symbol 'as ?
The symbol 'in isn't a only pattern with 'in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro patterns are not evaluated. In particular, `'as` is *not* a symbol. It is simply the list `(quote as)`. (`'as` *evaluates* to a symbol, but it isn't by itself a symbol.) Thus, your macro is really the same as:

```
(define-syntax for
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ list (quote as) element body ...)
     (map (lambda (element)
            body ...)
          list))))
```

where `quote` and `as` are pattern variables that can match anything whatsoever.

As mentioned in uselpa's answer, the correct way to require the use of `as` exactly as written is to use the literal list:

```
(define-syntax for
  (syntax-rules (as)
    ((_ list as element body ...)
     (map (lambda (element)
            body ...)
          list))))
```

Or, if you're really sadistic and want to make the user quote the `as`, do this:

```
(define-syntax for
  (syntax-rules (quote as)
    ((_ list 'as element body ...)
     (map (lambda (element)
            body ...)
          list))))
```

(Yes, you can even change the literal list to be `'as` instead of `(quote as)` as I have it, but that just makes your macro unreadable. Don't do that. :-P)

Answer (score 1):

In the Racket doc, [at some point](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html) it says

> The template is used in place of a form that matches the pattern, except that each instance of a pattern variable in the template is replaced with the part of the macro use the pattern variable matched.

which makes me think that the `'as` symbol is simply ignored. And indeed, this

```
(define-syntax for
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ list element body ...)
     (map (lambda (element)
            body ...)
          list))))
(for '(0 1 2 3 4) i (print i) (newline))
```

works just as well.

To get the behaviour you want, use

```
(define-syntax for
  (syntax-rules (as)
    ((_ list as element body ...)
     (map (lambda (element)
            body ...)
          list))))
```

then

```
>  (for '(0 1 2 3 4) as i (print i) (newline))
0
1
2
3
4
'(#<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void>)
```

but

```
>  (for '(0 1 2 3 4) in i (print i) (newline))    
for: bad syntax in: (for (quote (0 1 2 3 4)) in i (print i) (newline))
```

Comment: Yeah， I know your code can work well。 
But i think my code can only match the (for '(0 1 2 3 4) 'as i (print i) (newline)),but it can match with (for '(0 1 2 3 4) 'in i (print i) (newline)) let me feel very confused.

Comment: Yeah,like the (list element and body) all is a pattern variable.But in my code 'as is a symbol and not a variable.So i think it can't match 'in.But it still can work with (for '(0 1 2 3 4) 'in i (print i) (newline)).

Comment: @firebroo As I said, the pattern variables get substituted, and symbols get ignored, as long as the relative positions match. But there's at least one Racket Dev here so he may have a more precise explanation. FWIW, I see the same behaviour in Bigloo, but Guile gives an error message as expected with your code.

Comment: +1 for correctly suggesting the use of the literal list. The reason using `'as` doesn't work is that that is read as `(quote as)` (and not as a symbol---remember, `'as` is only a symbol when evaluated, and macros are pre-evaluation), where both `quote` and `as` are pattern variables (matching any datum at all).